# Replace TOP 1 in H2 SQL that it works with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, translate

I have this SQL for an H2 database:

```
update EVENT event
set event.SENT_INTO_WF_BY_ID = (
  select TOP 1 eventRev.USER_ID
  from EVENT_REV eventRev
  where eventRev.EVENT_ID = event.EVENT_ID
  and eventRev.STATUS != (
    select TOP 1 eventRev2.STATUS
    from EVENT_REV eventRev2
    where VALID_FROM is not null
    and eventRev.EVENT_ID = eventRev2.EVENT_ID
    order by VALID_FROM asc
  )
  order by eventRev.VALID_TO asc nulls last
)
where event.SENT_INTO_WF_BY_ID is null
```

and I have to translate it to make it work for Oracle. In Oracle the "TOP" doesn't exist, so I tried this:

```
update EVENT event
set event.SENT_INTO_WF_BY_ID = (
  select eventRev.USER_ID
  from ( select eventRev.USER_ID from EVENT_REV eventRev
         where eventRev.EVENT_ID = event.EVENT_ID
         order by eventRev.VALID_TO asc nulls last )
  where rownum = 1

)
where event.SENT_INTO_WF_BY_ID is null;
```

But this gives me the error:

> *Error: ORA-00904: "event"."EVENT_ID": invalid identifier*

Is there a solution with not even more nested selects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge`, but there is a way to solve this problem using `update`.  That is using the `keep` functionality:

```
update EVENT e
    set e.SENT_INTO_WF_BY_ID = 
          (select max(er.USER_ID) keep (dense_rank first order by er.VALID_TO asc nulls last)
           from EVENT_REV er
           where er.EVENT_ID = e.EVENT_ID
          )
    where e.SENT_INTO_WF_BY_ID is null;
```

The problem you are encountering is because of the scoping rules in Oracle.  Oracle only recognizes aliases from the outer query, one level deep.

Comment: Works like a charme! Thank you.